# Asynchronous image listing and caching in android

Tags: android, caching, image-caching

I'm new to android and need help with  best examples which shows asynchronous image listing(set of images ). And interested to know the concept of image caching . How can we use low memory for image listing ?

Comment: try lazy list view for an example of how to cache images and display it from net - asynchronously

Comment: @droidhot thnku ..nice recommendation..

Comment: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/541966/1050058)

Answer (score 1):

See the developers documentation, it shows some options to manage images:

[Android developers: displaying bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: If you have questions after read that deeply (I hope that), comment ; ) This is a interesting issue with no easy solutions

Comment: one simple ques ..I have some json/xml encoded data (like 10 image url's)..You have any idea how can i insert that data in to array dynamically?(I have no idea about the size of data  :) )

Comment: If data comes from json/xml, then you need to parse that json/xml and build your data model. You must know the structure of the json/xml and then develop a parser. Can you write here a sample of the json/xml you receive?

Answer (score 0):

see:

a example : https://github.com/tingzi/android-app